# Getting average from 3 columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table with 3 columns (`smallint`) in SQL Server 2005.

```
Table Ratings
ratin1 smallint,
ratin2 smallint
ratin3 smallint
```

These columns can have values from `0` to `5`.

How can I select the average value of these fields, but only compare fields where the value is greater then `0`.

So if the column values are `1`, `3` ,`5` - the average has to be `3`.
if the values are `0`, `3`, `5` - The average has to be `4`.

Comment: What's the average when all three are 0?

Comment: To clarify -- you want to find the average of ratin1, ratin2, and ratin3 in a single row, right?

Comment: if all are 0 then I need to get 0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is kind of quick and dirty, but it will work...

```
SELECT (ratin1 + ratin2 + ratin3) / 
((CASE WHEN ratin1 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) + 
(CASE WHEN ratin2 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) + 
(CASE WHEN ratin3 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
(CASE WHEN ratin1 = 0 AND ratin2 = 0 AND ratin3 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Average
```

Comment: when the three are 0 you would get division by zero, isn't it?

Comment: + (CASE WHEN ratin 1 = 0 AND ratin2 = 0 AND ratin3 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

Answer (score 1):

@mwigdahl - this breaks if any of the values are `NULL`. Use the `NVL` (value, default) to avoid this:

[Sum columns with null values in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590551/sum-columns-with-null-values-in-oracle)

Edit: This only works in Oracle. In TSQL, try encapsulating each field with an `ISNULL()` statement.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an aggregate average function for sql server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx

Comment: There is, but the questioner wants to average across columns, not across rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is trickier than it looks, but you can do this:

```
SELECT dbo.MyAvg(ratin1, ratin2, ratin3) from TableRatings
```

If you create this function first:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyAvg]
(
    @a int,
    @b int,
    @c int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result int
    DECLARE @divisor int
    SELECT @divisor = 3

    IF @a = 0 BEGIN SELECT @divisor = @divisor - 1 END
    IF @b = 0 BEGIN SELECT @divisor = @divisor - 1 END
    IF @c = 0 BEGIN SELECT @divisor = @divisor - 1 END

    IF @divisor = 0     
        SELECT @result = 0
    ELSE
        SELECT @result = (@a + @b + @c) / @divisor

    RETURN @Result

END
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
(
    select avg(v) 
    from (values (Ratin1), (Ratin2), (Ratin3)) as value(v)
) as average
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the AVG() function.  This will get the average for a column.  So, you could nest a SELECT statement with the AVG() methods and then SELECT these values.

Pseudo:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
  FROM (
    SELECT AVG(col1) AS col1, AVG(col2) AS col2, AVG(col3) AS col3
      FROM table
) as tbl
WHERE col1 IN (0, 3, 5)
etc.
```

Comment: I really don't think this is what the questioner wants.  As I read it, he wants to average ratin1, ratin2, and ratin3 within the context of a single row.

Comment: If that is the case, then they can just amend the first SELECT statement to say SELECT AVG(col1 + col2 + col3)

Comment: `AVG(col1 + col2 + col3)` is the sum of col1, col2, and col3 for single rows

Comment: What about fields with zero value, I wouldn't like to include it in average, see my question.