# Oracle Documentation NOT NVL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I'm doing some converting from Oracle to MSSQL and I was reading a guide by Oracle on [B Supported SQL Syntax and Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/gateways.102/b14270/apb.htm#i634543).

I noticed it was stated that there is a NOT NVL function (and its MSSQL equivalent was IS NOT NULL).

I'm compiling a list for my colleagues so we can have a one-stop resource for syntax and supported functions, am I correct in assuming that NOT NVL works like so:

> There are 3 columns, name, location, loves_marmite
>
> Andrew | UK | Yes

NOT NVL(loves_marmite, 'Nope')

So the data displayed would be:

```
Andrew | UK | Nope
```

I just don't get why it would be listed as an Oracle Function when it's just a logic issue, and what's more is that Oracle has **IS NULL** and **IS NOT NULL**.

I'm sorry I'm just looking for some clarification before I pass this document on to my colleagues.

**EDIT :**  If possible would someone have a comprehensive list of function and syntax differences between the two platforms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [`NVL2(param1, param2, param3)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2049.htm#OLADM625http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2049.htm#OLADM625) function.

If param1 is `NOT (NULL or EMPTY STRING)` it returns param2 else returns param3.

You could write:

```
NVL2(loves_marmite, 'Nope', something_else)
```

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/590572/25732) for a list of null-related functions in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

First, please see the [isNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms184325.aspx) function. But Oracle may be trying to tell you to replace the NVL funcionality with a case;

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Foo IS NOT NULL THEN bar
                                 ELSE BLA
             END
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the ISNULL function and the CASE statement but the context of the guide by Oracle would be NOT ISNULL. If that's understandable, I just do not know why it was mentioned. 

I'm just looking for some clarification for this document I'm creating.

Comment: I my opinion NOT NVL() is just NOT isNull() and doing not to a string is not what you wanted. In Oracle there is the nvl2 but is SQL there is no IsNotNull as far as I know