# Automatic Fetch one record

Tags: sql, oracle

I am execute below query. there are no data but SQL Nevigator fetch ONE record and this record are show the blank. so i want no fetch any record.

```
select sum(arrears_edutax) 
  from view_govtax_rpt 
    where trunc(receiptdt) between  '01-Oct-2019' and '14-Oct-2019';
```

But dont use Group BY function.

[image]

Comment: why are you restricting the use of group by?

Comment: i want all data.

Comment: Looks like column `ARREARS_EDUTAX` can have null values. Have you seen [Sum columns with null values in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590551/sum-columns-with-null-values-in-oracle)?

Comment: If you need all data you cannot use sum in this way. you need to use window function

Comment: I am Already use is not,NVL,ISNULL and trim but they are not work. @Abra

Comment: But i want diff-diff date a data.. so i have need to group by.

Comment: It's really not clear what problem you're trying to solve. I made a guess but I think my answer has solved your problem. So I suggest you post some sample data and your desired output derived from that sample.

Comment: i am type wrong Sorry For mistake. I want diff-diff date from database . so i dont need group by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there are no data but SQL Nevigator fetch ONE record and this record are show the blank. so i want no fetch any record

That's not how aggregate queries work.

An aggregate query with no GROUP BY returns one row. The result is the aggregation applied to the filtered rows. Because you had no rows which matched your criteria the aggregated value is NULL. If you had used a COUNT() function instead you would have got zero.

So, if you really want an empty result set (zero rows) when there's no matching data you can use this trick:

```
select sum(arrears_edutax) 
from view_govtax_rpt 
where trunc(receiptdt) between  date '2019-10-01' and date '2019-10-14'
having count(*) > 0
;
```

Incidentally, you should get into the habit of using date literals instead of relying on implicit data conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Quick demonstration about what you need

```
with w0 as 
(
  select 1 x from dual union
  select 2 from dual
), w1 as
(
   select * from w0 where 1=2
)
select c1 from (
  select sum(x) c1 from w1
)
where c1 is not null
```

[Click here for demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/97eade/2832)

Comment: Its Not Work.. that through only fetch 0 record.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
 select sum(null) c1 from dual where 1=2
```

No data due to `1=2` but one row result

[image]

Comment: Ok. I understand. Thank you